# Logging from a storm bolt - where is it going?

Tags: slf4j, apache-storm

I have several bolts deployed to a topology on a cluster. Each is configured to log via **slf4j**. On the test machine I get both the **stdout** and the **file** appenders working fine.

When I deploy this to the cluster the logging seems to have disappeared. I don't get anything in the storm logs (on the supervisor machines), to /var/log/* or anywhere else as far as I can tell.

Should I be able to use a logging system inside a storm worker? If so, is there a trick to getting the messages?

Machines are all running CentOS 6.6 x64

Answer (score 4):

This blog post suggest a method to find location of log files on storm cluster.
http://www.saurabhsaxena.net/how-to-find-storm-worker-log-directory/

When topology is deployed on cluster, topology logs are written in worker*.log files.

As mentioned in the blog post

- First step would be to fine the log directory location. This can be done using 'ps' command. Search for nimbus process
  $ ps aux|grep nimbus
- Look for -Dstorm.log.dir in the output.
- Go to log dir and look into worker*.log file for topology logs.

Comment: Those are the logs for storm. I'm looking for the logs that my topology should be outputting.

Comment: @ethrbunny When topology is deployed on cluster, topology logs are written in worker*.log files.

Comment: Link archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20160404004949/http://saurabhsaxena.net/how-to-find-storm-worker-log-directory/

Answer (score 4):

In my case (using the official storm docker image) logs were in the supervisor container:

```
/logs/workers-artifacts/MyTopology-1-123123123/123/worker.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `storm.workers.artifacts.dir` parameter in storm.yaml and from now on, workers artifacts (including logs) will be saved in that path in a folder which is named after your topology name.