# Apache Storm 1.1.1 - where to find my log files?

Tags: log4j2, apache-storm

I have checked these questions:

[Logging from a storm bolt - where is it going?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720472/logging-from-a-storm-bolt-where-is-it-going)

And the solution is not working anymore.

In theory, the system variable of `storm.log.dir` is set when we launch `storm jar`. As the solution suggests, you can use `ps aux | grep storm.log.dir` to search the argument's value.

It shows:

```
java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/opt/apache-storm-1.1.1 -Dstorm.log.dir=/opt/apache-storm-1.1.1/logs .....
```

But, when I go there, I have:

```
[root@xxx ~]# ls -la /opt/apache-storm-1.1.1/logs
total 58272
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Jan 15 01:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Oct 31 10:09 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Nov  3 10:46 access-logviewer.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Oct 31 10:09 access-nimbus.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Oct 31 10:09 access-supervisor.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Nov 23 14:36 access-ui.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     8916 Nov 27 17:34 access-web-logviewer.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Oct 31 10:09 access-web-nimbus.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Oct 31 10:09 access-web-supervisor.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    31661 Nov 27 17:40 access-web-ui.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     2247 Nov  3 11:34 logviewer.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Nov  3 10:46 logviewer.log.metrics
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    20690 Oct 31 10:09 nimbus.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Oct 31 10:09 nimbus.log.metrics
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 46713727 Feb  6 17:13 supervisor.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3143062 Jan 10 08:23 supervisor.log.1.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3104009 Jan 11 22:06 supervisor.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3103550 Jan 13 11:43 supervisor.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3103899 Jan 15 01:21 supervisor.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Oct 31 10:09 supervisor.log.metrics
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   401456 Nov 27 17:40 ui.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 Nov 23 14:36 ui.log.metrics
drwxr-xr-x 48 root root     4096 Feb 12 18:08 workers-artifacts
```

Entering `workers-artifacts`, I have dirs named after nodes, and inside, I have `worker.yaml`.

```
[root@mq1-acustats-process KafkaStormRadius-1-1518455061]# cd 1027

[root@mq1-acustats-process 1027]# ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  24 Feb 12 18:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root  72 Feb 12 18:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 109 Feb 12 18:04 worker.yaml

[root@mq1-acustats-process 1027]# cat worker.yaml
worker-id: 33e6e77d-8a7b-48b2-b2d4-1be0af726c52
logs.users: []
logs.groups: []
topology.submitter.user: root
```

So, no logs here. Where are they?

I have this `worker.xml` under `{STORM_DIR}/log4j2`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<configuration monitorInterval="60" shutdownHook="disable">
<properties>
    <property name="pattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %c{1.} %t [%p] %msg%n</property>
    <property name="patternNoTime">%msg%n</property>
    <property name="patternMetrics">%d %-8r %m%n</property>
</properties>
<appenders>
    <RollingFile name="A1"
        fileName="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}"
        filePattern="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}.%i.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="9"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="radius"
        fileName="${sys:storm.log.dir}/radius.log"
        filePattern="${sys:storm.log.dir}/radius.log.%i.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/> <!-- Or every 20 MB -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="9"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="STDOUT"
        fileName="${sys:storm.log.dir}/radius.out"
        filePattern="${sys:storm.log.dir}/radius.out.%i.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${patternNoTime}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="STDERR"
        fileName="${sys:storm.log.dir}/radius.err"
        filePattern="${sys:storm.log.dir}/radius.err.%i.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${patternNoTime}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="METRICS"
        fileName="${sys:storm.log.dir}/radius.metrics"
        filePattern="${sys:storm.log.dir}/radius.metrics.%i.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${patternMetrics}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="9"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <Syslog name="syslog" format="RFC5424" charset="UTF-8" host="localhost" port="514"
        protocol="UDP" appName="[${sys:storm.id}:${sys:worker.port}]" mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true"
        facility="LOCAL5" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true" exceptionPattern="%rEx{full}"
        messageId="[${sys:user.name}:${sys:logging.sensitivity}]" id="storm" immediateFail="true" immediateFlush="true"/>
</appenders>
<loggers>
    <root level="info"> <!-- We log everything -->
        <appender-ref ref="A1"/>
        <appender-ref ref="syslog"/>
    </root>
    <Logger name="org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="METRICS"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.joestelmach.natty" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="radius"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="STDERR" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDERR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="syslog"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="STDOUT" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="syslog"/>
    </Logger>
</loggers>
</configuration>
```

But, I don't see `radius.log` created under `${sys:storm.log.dir}`.

Why?

By the way:

- difference between `cluster.xml` and `worker.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read the documentation left by another team and found these lines.... I have a service of storm not launched.

```
systemctl start storm-supervisor
```

Checking the service definition under `/etc/systemd/system/` (I am with CentOS so I am using `systemd`), and it reads:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nimbus Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=0s
ExecStart=/opt/apache-storm/bin/storm supervisor

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After launching that, I now see log files created under the correct dir.

Worth to mention that I also changed two other things:

- Use `slf4j` instead of `log4j`.
- Change the `log4j2.properties` to use an absolute path (under `/tmp`) instead of reading the system variable like `{sys:storm.log.dir}` in order to discard a variable factor.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the storm.log.dir variable isn't being correctly set for the worker JVM. Remember that the JVM you start when running `storm jar` isn't the same JVM that will run your topology.

In order to set VM options for your workers, you can use the worker.childopts variable in storm.yaml to set options globally (you might want to make sure to copy over the defaults from https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.1.1/conf/defaults.yaml#L171 if you do this), or topology.worker.childopts in your topology config to set them per topology.

For example, I get logs printed to E:\testLogs with the following config:

storm.yaml

```
worker.childopts: "-Dstorm.log.dir=E:\\testLogs"
```

worker.xml

```
...
<RollingFile name="A1"
    fileName="${sys:storm.log.dir}/worker.log"
    filePattern="${sys:workers.artifacts}/${sys:storm.id}/${sys:worker.port}/${sys:logfile.name}.%i.gz">
    <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/> <!-- Or every 100 MB -->
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="9"/>
</RollingFile>
...
```

where the rest of the worker.xml is the default one shipping with Storm 1.1.1.

Regarding cluster.xml and worker.xml, cluster.xml is the logging configuration for the Storm daemons (Nimbus, Supervisor, UI etc.), and worker.xml is the logging configuration for the worker processes (the ones running your topology components)

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light into this. I have managed to look further into the doc left by another team and found another thing. See below.